# Print Custom String With the Sum of Three Lists

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

When I run the following code:

```
main = do

    let smallTriplets xs ys zs = [ (x, y, z) | x <- xs, y <- ys, z <- zs, let sum = x + y + z, sum <= 10]
    print (smallTriplets [1,2] [3,4] [5,6])
```

It gives the output:

```
[(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,5),(2,3,5)]
```

However, I want `smallTriplets` to print the `sum` with some customization. To be more specific, it will be better if I could replace `let sum = x + y + z` in `smallTriplets` with some code so that it gives output like:

```
Sum is 1+3+5 = 9
Sum is 1+3+6 = 10
Sum is 1+4+5 = 10
Sum is 2+3+5 = 10
```

I am expecting that code to have a string like `"Sum is " ++ show(x) ++ "+" ++ show(y) ++ "+" ++ show(z) ++ " = " ++ show(x + y + z) ++ "\n"`

How can I do that?

If this is not possible then please show me how to print:

```
Sum is 1+3+5 = 9
Sum is 1+3+6 = 10
Sum is 1+4+5 = 10
Sum is 2+3+5 = 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem of writing `"Sum is " ++ show x ++ "+" ++ show y ++ "+" ++ show z ++ " = " ++ show sum` instead of `(x, y, z)`?

You could like this

```hs
main = do
  let helper x y z s = "Sum is " ++ show x ++ "+" ++ show y ++ "+" ++ show z ++ " = " ++ show s
  let smallTriplets xs ys zs = [ helper x y z sum | x <- xs, y <- ys, z <- zs, let sum = x + y + z, sum <= 10]
  putStr $ unlines $ smallTriplets [1,2] [3,4] [5,6]
```

Here, `smallTriplets` returns a `[String]` instead of a `[(,,)]`; `unlines` converts the `[String]` to a `String` with embedded `\n`s; finally, `putStr` prints the string.

---

This is a quick and dirty solution which alters the function `smallTriplets`, so if you planned to use the original result in other ways this solution will not help.

If your aim is to log things you do, then a more complex solution is needed. Maybe using the writer monad?

Comment: Can I do it without using `unlines`, by appending `++ "\n"` at the end?

Comment: @AhmadIsmail, why would you ever do that?

Comment: I am new to haskell so wanted to know how I can do that.

Comment: Then learn that [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) exits, try the _Example searches_ in the middle of the page and see what they give to you. [Then search for `unlines`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=unlines&scope=set%3Astackage), [click on it](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unlines), and finally [click on the `# Source` link on the right of the screen](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#unlines) to see how it's implemented.